# How to edit the factor label names using MJCA and ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a graph following use of mjca using ggplot2 that includes only the level name in the label and not the factor:level.
See example - how can i manipulate these factor:level labels?

```
library(ca)
library(ggplot2)

data("wg93")

mj <-mjca(wg93, supcol = 5:7, lambda = "JCA")

summary(mj)

cats = apply(wg93, 2, function(x) nlevels(as.factor(x)))

cats

# eigenvalues
mj$sv^2

# column coordinates
head(mj$colcoord)

# row coordinates
head(mj$rowcoord)

# data frame for ggplot
mca4_vars_df = data.frame(mj$colcoord, Variable = rep(names(cats), cats))
rownames(mca4_vars_df) = mj$levelnames

#plot
ggplot(data =mca4_vars_df, 
       aes(x = X1, y = X2, label = rownames(mca4_vars_df))) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, colour = "gray70") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, colour = "gray70") +
  geom_text(aes(colour = Variable)) +
  ggtitle("MCA plot of variables using R package ca")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute everything before the colon with blank:

```
ggplot(data =mca4_vars_df, 
       aes(x = X1, y = X2, label = sub('.*:','',rownames(mca4_vars_df)))) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, colour = "gray70") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, colour = "gray70") +
  geom_text(aes(colour = Variable)) +
  ggtitle("MCA plot of variables using R package ca")
```